# Social Media sharing Buttons in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-media

I'm trying to add custom social media sharing buttons in a blog app in Ruby on Rails. It is important for me that a pop-up window will show for sharing the "post" meaning I want to include Javascript.

Unfortunately this code does not work:

```
  <!-- Twitter -->
  <a oneclick="javascript:window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=<%= @post.title %> 
  by Martin Bortowski - &amp;url=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>',
  '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>

  <!-- Facebook -->
  <a oneclick="javascript:window.open('http://facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>',
  '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>

  <!-- Google Plus -->
  <a oneclick="javascript:window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>',
  '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
```

When I click on a button nothing happens. What I am missing? Can someone help me please? If you need further information just let me know.

Comment: i know this is old and you have already used a gem for this, But you had "oneclick" instead of "onclick"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are number of gems available in ruby on rails for implementing social shairing feature below are few links

1. https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button
2. https://github.com/hermango/shareable

Comment: I have used the social share button gem and it worked perfectly! I have used this tutorial https://richonrails.com/articles/adding-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-rails-app

Comment: that's great! :)