# How to create facebook sharing functionality when using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, facebook-share

I am using Ruby on Rails and I am trying to create facebook sharing functionality for a webpage. In https://developers.facebook.com under Sharing Debugger tab, when I put https://www.rupeevest.com/ in url and clicked on Debug, it works fine.

But when I put another page like https://www.rupeevest.com/Mutual-Funds-India/Motilal-Oswal-Mutual-Fund/MOSt-Focused-Multicap-35-Fund-Reg(G)/26481
, it does not work.

I got something like

`{"schemedata":[{"schemecode"....`

Even when I click on the link 'See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL' It shows

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body><p>{"schemedata":[{"schemecode"....}]}</p></body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this issue? Please share with me if anyone has any idea.

Comment: ref link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066371/social-media-sharing-buttons-in-ruby-on-rails/43067155#43067155

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Social Media sharing Buttons in Ruby on Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066371/social-media-sharing-buttons-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: You can use this gem: https://github.com/huacnlee/social-share-button

Answer (score 1):

You can try out this method from addtoany, just include these codes on the page/place you want to have the sharing buttons. You can refer to the link for additional info.

```
<!-- AddToAny BEGIN -->
<div class="a2a_kit a2a_kit_size_32 a2a_default_style">
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_twitter"></a>
<a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
</div>
<script async src="https://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js"></script>
<!-- AddToAny END -->
```

https://www.addtoany.com/buttons/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21345148)

Comment: @sme New to answer questions, thank you for the suggestion. Would answering this way be more appropriate?

Comment: Yea, the answer is fine now